# Drupal 7 taxonomy

Tags: drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7 and i want to get all the article listed under that taxonomy named (Slider). i want to get it in frontend how can i do it
i am new to drupal so not much know about it

Thanks in advance

Comment: HI There just curious to see if you got this working. I managed to use views module. I created a block and i have the content i need but none of my jquery sliders seem to work. How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the url `exemple.com/taxonomy/term/[TermID]` where `TermID` is the id of "Slider".

Comment: Thanks for replying  
i am in big problem i want to make an image gallery with text sliding over image in the home page can i do with that with views. i am using drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to handle this is to use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module. Most Drupal sites are using Views, so if you're new to Drupal, it is highly recommended to learn how to use this module.

There are a lot of tutorials out there, any web search with "Drupal Views tutorials" should return a fairly long list!